# Keyboard strokes do not input into selected program

Tags: keyboard

I have two computers, each partitioned with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Computer A has served me well for many years but lately the  keyboard connected to Ubuntu will not input the keystrokes into any program. This happens in Firefox , in Libreoffice,in Thunderbird and other programs.

My trouble shooting of the keyboard consisted of using a different known serviceable one and using different USB inputs to the computer, and I have concluded that the keyboard is not at fault. A knowledgeable friend and I searched through Settings yesterday without finding anything that might be pertinent, but without result. Computer B is OK.

Comment: "served for many year" leads me to my standard question: "Have you checked the Bios battery?"